# How to click on "next" button using selenium or scrapy in python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, scrapy, data-mining

I was trying to scrape some data from flipkart.com using scrapy.
I got everything other than going to the next page.
first I tried using scrapy followed by selenium.
actually, a class has 2links for the previous page and for the next page.

with scrapy:
I am unable to fetch any result. I am getting the blank output.

with selenium:
whenever I try to click on the next page it works fine from page 1 to page 2.
but then instead of going on the 3rd page, it's coming back to the second page.

is there any other way to do this?
how should I distinguish the URLs for the previous page and the next page?

Comment: please share your code

Comment: You can change the page number directly in the URL: `https://www.flipkart.com/...&page=3`.

Comment: I'd suggest changing the URL like @YevhenKuzmovych says (preferably using scrapy), since the xpath of elements might change everytime you click next. The xpath may also vary depending on the products category

Comment: thanks @YevhenKuzmovych It is working...

Answer (score 1):

just append [-1] so that driver only fetches the last occurring result for the given class/id
for flipkart the code is as follows

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//a[@class="_1LKTO3"]')[-1].click()
```